# Converting varchar to int, SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date

I have code like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION gantistok (@id   VARCHAR(8),
                           @id_t INT)
RETURNS INT
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @tahu  INT,
              @tempe INT,
              @hasil INT;

      SELECT @tahu = CONVERT(INT, stok)
      FROM   barang
      WHERE  id_barang = @id;

      SELECT @tempe = CONVERT(INT, jumlah)
      FROM   det_trans
      WHERE  id_det_trans = @id_t;

      SET @hasil = @tahu - @tempe;

      RETURN @hasil
  END
```

Why doesn't it work? I am getting this error:

```
Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Procedure gantistok, Line 5
The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.
```

Comment: convert function works ok, problem is on id_barang = @id. id_barang contains a value that RDBMS is not able to convert to integer.

Comment: What is the datatype of `id_barang`? Is it `text`? If so why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using wrong syntax

it should be

`CONVERT(expr,type)`

and *type* must be `SIGNED` [INTEGER]

[`REFERENCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert)

Comment: This is not the correct answer. The OP is on SQL Server where the syntax they are using [is correct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). The error message they are getting indicates that they are doing an equality comparison between a column of `text` datatype and one of `varchar`

Comment: tag is `mysql`, thats why i suggest this

Comment: The error message is definitely SQL Server. I changed the tag.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL? SQL Server? which one?

What is type of id_barang stok for table barang?

Guessing the problem expression is id_barang=@id

The SQL Server convert() function does not allow convert TEXT to int(INT4).

Answer (score 0):

> problem is on id_barang = @id.
>   id_barang contains a value that RDBMS is not able to convert to integer.

`id_barang` is a varchar.
So if you can't convert `id_barang` to integer, then you have to convert `@id` to varchar in the query:

```
  SELECT @tahu = CONVERT(INT, stok)
  FROM   barang
  WHERE  id_barang = CONVERT(varchar(50), @id);
```

I'm using `varchar(50)` because I don't know what kind of varchar exactly id_barang is.

I would suggest to **always** do it this way.
Even if `id_barang` would not contain non-integer values at the moment...it's still a text column!
Someone could insert a non-integer value anytime, so I would always make sure that my queries will work in this case as well.

Comment: It's nothing to do with integers. The error message the OP is getting is simply because the column is of `text` datatype and it is forbidden to use `=` against a `varchar` without casting the `text` column to `varchar` first.